# Kubernetes on Azure, how do I reuse an existing disk in a new PersistentVolume?

Tags: kubernetes, azure

I currently have a *managed Azure disk* created from a Azure disk snapshot of a *Kubernetes Persistent Volume* that no longer exists.

I would like to know how to reuse the restored disk in a new 'PersistentVolumeClaim', otherwise K8s will request Azure to create a new empty disk.

My current K8s PersistentVolumeClaim config:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-master-vol-claim
  annotations: 
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: managed-standard
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to 'restore' this snapshot into the newly created volume handled by k8s ?

Comment: I've tried that, but it looks like Azure allows us only to use a 'disk snapshot' as a 'parameter' to create the new disk.

Comment: In other words, one existing managed disk can't use a snapshot from another disk.

Comment: @YgorThomaz Could you post the comments as an answer?

Comment: I have a similar question which I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774021/how-to-configure-a-manually-provisioned-azure-managed-disk-to-use-as-a-kuberntes

Comment: `I would like to know how to reuse the restored disk in a new 'PersistentVolumeClaim',` Why?